# jasmine-jQuery, How to test for form fill out and change of HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to test for the filling out of an HTML form and the subsequent change of an HTML elements Text. I need to create some form of event using jasmine-jquery...

HTML

```html
<div class="response" id="text-response">Unknown</div>

<div class="form-holder">
  <form>
    <input id="input-text" type="text" name="user-input" placeholder="Test Your Text" value="">
    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to test drive id='text-response' changing to 'Correct' based on some script logic.

```
  describe('Interface logic', function(){

      it('Will return correct if logic applies', function(){
        expect('#emotion').toContainText('Correct');
      });

    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submit-button').click();
```

Was the solution for me but the spec runner constant refresh is because you're hitting http://localhost:3000/specs/ rather than http://localhost:3000/SpecRunner.html

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to trigger an event, for example:

```
$('#submit-button').click();
```

That should fire the click event. Then you can check for whatever condition this event changes on the page.

Comment: This makes sense although for some reason when I use ```.click()``` rather than ```.trigger()``` it causes my SpecRunner to constantly refresh, I have tested it using both chrome and firefox, any ideas?

Comment: I bet it's firing a page post / reload. You can try doing a `e.preventDefault()`. This will keep on the same page without a server post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your form html in a separate template in a file named for example

```
templates/form.tmpl.html
```

and your jquery in a separate file also named for example

```
js/validation.js
```

And containing validation code like

```
$(".form-holder").on("submit", function() {

  event.preventDefault();

  var userInput = $('#input-text').val();

  if (userInput === 'the correct text') {
    $('#text-response').text('Correct');
    return;
  }

  $('#text-response').text('Incorrect');
});
```

Then your test spec can be something similar to this

```
describe('Interface logic', function() {

    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '';

    beforeEach(function() {
        loadFixtures('templates/form.tmpl.html');
        appendSetFixtures('<script src="js/validation.js"></script>')
    });

    it('Will return correct if logic applies', function(){
      $('#input-text').val('the correct text');
      $('#submit-button').trigger("click");
      expect($('#text-response').text()).toBe('Correct');
    });

    it('Will return incorrect if logic applies', function(){
      $('#input-text').val('the incorrect text');
      $('#submit-button').trigger("click");
      expect($('#text-response').text()).toBe('Incorrect');
    });

});
```

And the spec runner html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.3/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2/boot.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="specs/form.spec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still not working, I am wondering if it is an issue with the server I have a Node/Express server running like so... ```var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var root = __dirname + '/'

app.use(express.static(root))

app.get('/index', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(root + 'index.html');
});

app.get('/spec', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(root + 'SpecRunner.html');
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
});

module.exports = server;```